# the derivative of $\sqrt[\beta]{x^\alpha}$

Tags: derivatives

Please someone tell me what it's wrong with this procedure

$\frac d{dx} \sqrt[\beta]{x^\alpha} = \frac d{dx}x^\frac \alpha\beta$

\begin{align*}
\frac d{dx} x^\frac \alpha\beta & = \frac \alpha\beta x^{\frac \alpha\beta -1} \\[10pt]
& = \frac \alpha\beta x^{\frac \alpha\beta - \frac \beta\beta} \\[10pt]
& = \frac \alpha\beta x^{\frac{\alpha\beta - \beta^2}\beta} \\[10pt]
& = \frac \alpha\beta x^{\alpha - \beta} \\[10pt]
& = \frac \alpha\beta x^\alpha \cdot x^{-\beta} \\[10pt]
& = \frac \alpha\beta x^\alpha \cdot \frac 1{x^\beta} \\[10pt]
& = \frac \alpha\beta \cdot \frac{x^\alpha}{x^\beta}
\end{align*}

---

$\frac d{dx}\sqrt{x}=\frac 1{2 \sqrt x}$

$$
\frac d{dx} \sqrt x = \frac d{dx} x^{\frac 12} \therefore \frac 12 \cdot \frac{x^1}{x^2}
$$

$$
\frac 12 \cdot \frac 1x = \frac 1{2x} \neq \frac 1{2\sqrt x}
$$

Comment: $x^{\frac \alpha\beta -1}  \not= x^{\alpha-\beta} $ so you have an error

Comment: Third equality is wrong, because $\alpha/\beta - \beta/\beta$ is equal to $(\alpha\beta-\beta^2)/\beta^2$, not $(\alpha\beta-\beta^2)/\beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you go from $$\frac{\alpha}{\beta} - \frac{\beta}{\beta}$$ to $$\frac{\alpha\beta - \beta^2}{\beta}?$$

The correct expression is $$\frac{\alpha}{\beta} - \frac{\beta}{\beta} = \frac{\alpha - \beta}{\beta}.$$  If you must insist on cross multiplying, you would have gotten

$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta} - \frac{\beta}{\beta} = \frac{\alpha \beta}{\beta^2} - \frac{\beta^2}{\beta^2} = \frac{\alpha \beta - \beta^2}{\beta^2}.$$